# How to put different bullets for different items (li) in html list (ol/ul)?

Tags: html, css

I would like li that have "ok" class to display a checked mark and li that have "ko" class to display a cross mark.

I am displaying thumbs up by default only for debug purpose in this example:

```css
ol {
  padding-left: 30px;
  list-style: none;
}

li:before {
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  content: '\1F44D';
}

.ok li:before {
  content: '\2714';
}

.ko li:before {
  content: '\274C';
}
```

```html
<ol id="opponentsOfCivOL">
  <li class="ok">1</li>
  <li class="ok">1</li>
  <li class="ok">1</li>
  <li class="ko">1</li>
  <li class="ok">1</li>
</ol>
```

What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: Did you know you can set a custom bullet using [`::marker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/::marker) rather than using _before_ with _content_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your CSS for `.ok` and `.ko`. Instead of it being `.ok li:before` it should be `li.ok:before`.

`li.ok` is read as find all elements with tag `li` with class name `ok`.

Whereas `.ok li` is read as find all elements with class name `ok` and all elements with tagname `li` inside it.

```
li.ok:before {
  content: '\2714';
}

li.ko:before {
  content: '\274C';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The classes "ok" and "ko" belong to the lis and have to be in the the css after "li".

**Working example**:

```css
ol {
    padding-left: 30px;
    list-style: none;
}

li:before {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    content: '\1F44D';
}

li.ok:before {
    content: '\2714';
}

li.ko:before {
    content: '\274C';
}
```

```html
<ol id="opponentsOfCivOL">
    <li class="ok">1</li>
    <li class="ok">1</li>
    <li class="ok">1</li>
    <li class="ko">1</li>
    <li class="ok">1</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your css selector for `li` with the classes is incorrect. See more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

```css
ol {
  padding-left: 30px;
  list-style: none;
}

li:before {
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  content: '\1F44D';
}

li.ok:before {
  content: '\2714';
}

li.ko:before {
  content: '\274C';
}
```

```html
<ol id="opponentsOfCivOL">
  <li class="ok">1</li>
  <li class="ok">1</li>
  <li class="ok">1</li>
  <li class="ko">1</li>
  <li class="ok">1</li>
</ol>
```